# NSURL with string giving null value

Tags: objective-c, url, ios6, nsurl, file-exists

Below is what I have

```
NSString *foofile = @"/Users/alkandari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8C445026-6387-4E40-B5A3-D1A1680666D6/Documents/ProjacsBODFiles/file_5_21.pdf"
NSURL *url;
if (fileExists) {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:foofile];
    NSLog(@"taking local file 1 ... %@==%@", url, foofile);
} else {

    url=[NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSLog(@"taking internet file 1... %@", url);
}
```

When I execute, I get log as below

```
taking local file 1 ... (null)==/Users/alkandari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8C445026-6387-4E40-B5A3-D1A1680666D6/Documents/ProjacsBODFiles/file_5_21.pdf
```

I don't understand why I am getting URL as null. Because of that I am not able to open file.

Any idea why I am getting URL as null above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `fileURLWithPath` for path to the localfile system:

```
NSString *foofile = @"/Users/alkandari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8C445026-6387-4E40-B5A3-D1A1680666D6/Documents/ProjacsBODFiles/file_5_21.pdf"
NSURL *url;
if (fileExists) {
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:foofile];
    NSLog(@"taking local file 1 ... %@==%@", url, foofile);
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also reach the file in your simulator folder by using the following code;

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *libraryBaseDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *privateDocumentsDirectory = [libraryBaseDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProjacsBODFiles"];
```